# Problems in analytically computing double integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am required to compute the following double integral as part of a thermal heating model I'm doing

$$I(x,y,t,t',R) = \int_A \exp(-\frac{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2}{4\alpha(t-t')})dx'dy'$$
Here, $A$ is the circle of radius $R$, centered at origin, and $x', y'$ are the coordinates in this system. $x,y,t,t'$ are constants for this integration. I realised that polar coordinates will have no use in simplifying the problem. I would like to know if this is separable into two separate integrals in $x'$ and $y'$.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by Paul, this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2330911/2d-gaussian-integration-over-arbitrary-eccentric-circle-analytical-solution) describes the problem I am trying to solve.

TLDR, analytical solution does not exist

Comment: Why did you decide against polar coordinates?

Comment: It won't help separating the $r$ and $\theta$ integrals I would get from switching to polar

Comment: I see, I didn't notice that $A$ was centred at the origin.

Comment: This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2330911/2d-gaussian-integration-over-arbitrary-eccentric-circle-analytical-solution) seems to be related.

Comment: Yup, it's a match